# Avoid `print` calls in production code. (Documentation)

Tags: flutter, dart

I started seeing this warning in all my `print` statements.

```dart
print('Foo'); // Warning: Avoid `print` calls in production code.
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is because of the [`flutter_lints`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) package which is implicitly added to new projects created after Flutter 2.3.0.

You can use any of the following solutions.

1. To remove the warning in that single line:

   ```dart
   // ignore: avoid_print
   print('Hello World');
   ```
2. To remove the warning in that file

   ```dart
   // ignore_for_file: avoid_print
   print('Hello World');
   ```
3. To remove the warning from the whole project.

   Open `analysis_options.yaml` file and add this linter rule:

   ```
   include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

   linter:
     rules:
       avoid_print: false
   ```

---

##### Why not `debugPrint` or `log`?

Although you can also use `debugPrint`, or `log` (from `dart:developer`), but there are a few reasons why I don't like them.

1. They both work only in Flutter apps (not Dart apps)
2. You'll have to manually import a library for them to work (importing is such a pain unless imports on fly is implemented in IDE)
3. They accept only a `String` as an argument, unlike `print` which accepts an `Object?` (everything)

Comment: Linting is the automated checking of your source code for programmatic and stylistic errors, so the best practice is to solve the error not to ignore it. At this point, It is better to use ```debugPrint()``` instead of ```print()``` method.

Answer (score 22):

Developers shouldn't suppress such analyzer warnings as well as not use `print()` for apps they are building. `print()` will print logs in release builds as well, which is something that shouldn't happen as some developers might log sensitive information.

The suggested by other people `debugPrint()` is just a wrapper for `print()` to avoid losing some logs on Android in case the `print()` function called too often or the output there is too big.

What should be used instead is `log()` function available in `dart.developer`, which allows to also attach an error object, severity level, name, etc. of the logged event and won't print anything in release mode, so no information will leak.

Here is more information about proper logging approach, which also describes `log()` function: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging#logging

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in a pure Dart app.

Answer (score 4):

I use to create a common function

```
void log(message) => print(message);
```

and whenever need to print something I just call log("Hello Word") and when I deploy, I make this function null. As print statement also reduces the performance of the app.

Answer (score 3):

If you're printing a lot of logs for debugging, it's better to use `debugPrint(String)` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69531976/1657333). Printing numerous amount of lines could sometimes lead the Android kernel to drop some of the lines if you're hitting the limit.

If using `print(String)` is really needed for your use-case, you're right on adding the lint check for `avoid_print` since it seems to be set to true by default.

Comment: But this still builds the string, allocates memory for it, and passes it to the debugPrint() function, only to be discarded eventually. Is there a way like the preprocessor directive #ifdef in C that does not compile the debugPrint() call in release mode?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do  try as below

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

...

developer.log("log instead of print");
```

Comment: This is already covered by other answers. You just added `as developer` to make it unique. Though this is not a very practical approach because in every file I need to use `log`, I'll manually have to type `as developer` in import and then use `developer.log`.

Answer (score 0):

other answers helps to avoid the warning, but why this warning appear and how to fix it?
using `print` method make your logs available to users when using `flutter logs` command, so if you log any sensitive data that would be dangerous,
does `debugPrint` solve this issue and print only in debug mode?
the answer is no, not by default, but the good point with `debugPrint` that you can override its behavior in a way that makes it not printing in release mode

```
void main() {
  if (kReleaseMode) {
    debugPrint = (String message, { int wrapWidth }) {} //
  }
}
```

Comment: You have copied this answer from other thread.

Comment: @iDecode
I think i need to mention the references of my answer
https://gpalma.pt/blog/debugprint/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CY5if4vkaCw&list=PLjxrf2q8roU3ahJVrSgAnPjzkpGmL9Czl&index=15
and some other articles, please add the answer url that i copied from?

Comment: You yourself better know which StackOverflow post you used to copy this answer from, so DIY.

Answer (score 0):

Null safe working version in 2022:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


void main() async {
   if (kReleaseMode) {
    debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) => '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

flutter enforces avoiding print statements after Dart version 2.5.0
[read here](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_print)

you can fix that by either checking the 'kDebugMode' or using debugPrint statements.

```
void f(int x) {
   debugPrint('debug: $x');
}
```

or

```
void f(int x) {
 if (kDebugMode) {
     print('debug: $x');
 }
}
```

A few things to  consider

1. both print & debug print work in all modes ( debug, profile or release ).
2. avoid any sort of logging in production code as that would be a waste of resources.
3. if the content is too long, print statements will stop logging after a certain length.  The same goes with debug print , but can be avoided by using 'wrapWidth' property

Answer (score -2):

Replace all `print(` to `logPrint(`

Create a new Function

```
logPrint(String s){print(s);}
```

And you can remark all the print commands in one line