# Avoid `print` calls in production code while using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

My code keeps giving me a warning...
**Avoid `print` calls in production code.**

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Don't use print statements then? I'm really not sure how this is a real question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid \`print\` calls in production code. (Documentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531248/avoid-print-calls-in-production-code-documentation)

Answer (score 7):

Use `debugPrint` instead. Just know that `debugPrint` can only take a `String?` so you might need to use `toString()` or correctly format the data you are trying to display.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

debugPrint('This is a debugPrint');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use print statement in only debug mode when app run in release mode print statement avoid. Write print using below both method:-

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (kDebugMode) {
      print("Hello");
    }
```

OR

```
debugPrint('This is a debugPrint');
```

Answer (score 2):

`Print()` is a function which helps you in debugging process, it's not a good idea to use it unconditionally, you may leak some sensitive information in Release version of your app

It's better to make sure that you're using this function in Debug mode

There are some options:

Using `debugPrint()` instead of `print()`

```
debugPrint('some debug info ...')
```

Using `assert()` function which will be called in Debug mode only

```
  assert(() {
    print('some debug info ...');
    return true;
  });
```

Checking Debug Mode before using `print()`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
...
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('some debug info ...');
  }
```

If you're sure that you have enough control on using `print()` function, you can ignore that warning by using `ignore` directive :

Use this on top of the file : `// ignore_for_file: avoid_print`

Or add this line before `print()` function

```
// ignore: avoid_print
print('some debug info ...');
```

To ignore that warning for the whole project, you can add this lines to `analysis_options.yaml` file of the project :

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    avoid_print: false
```