# Does the release version work on the debug console for everyone - flutter issue?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, google-play, release

Today, when I run my Flutter project on my phone, while waiting for it to run, I opened another app on my phone that I downloaded it from Google Play.
The strange thing is that the debug console started giving me debug information about the other app!, which I assume is a release version. Is this normal? How can I protect my app's information from this issue?

Note: The other app is not mine; I just downloaded it from the store to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal behaviour.

Actually, if you use `print` your linter [will complain](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_print):

[image]

You should instead use [`log()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-developer/log.html) from `dart:developer`

**See also**

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70914819/12349734) StackOverflow answer:

  > ... `print()` will print logs in *release builds* as well, which is something that shouldn't happen as some developers might log sensitive information.