debugPrint works in release version in flutter
in flutter when I run the app in release mode the debugPrint statements print data which I don't want to appear any ideas why this is happening ?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/76931009/12349734

debugPrint will print values in release mode. Its purpose is not to avoid print commands in release mode.
DebugPrint aims to avoid dropping messages on platforms that rate-limit their logging (for example, Android).
for example, you are trying to print a huge API response but it will not print full values because there is a set limit of statement length in a simple print command. Now, using debugPrint, you can print the whole response without limit.
Example
print("THIS IS A VERY BIG RESPONSE...") - Output THIS IS A VE....
debugPrint("THIS IS A VERY BIG RESPONSE...") - Output THIS IS A VERY BIG RESPONSE...
Note: In above example instead of "THIS IS A VERY BIG RESPONSE..."  assume a very big value.
for more infor please reffer to docs.
If you want to avoide print values in production. Create a method and use it.
void customPrint(String input)
{
if(kDebugMode) print(input);
}
 


That's how it is supposed to work. Maybe the name got you confused, but the docs are pretty clear:

The debugPrint function logs to console even in release mode. As per convention, calls to debugPrint should be within a debug mode check or an assert


You can disable all the debugPrint logs into production build by adding following code
void main() {
  if (kReleaseMode) {      
      debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) => null;
  } 

  runApp(
    MyApp()
  );
}

