# I am new to learning Dart, why can't I use print?

Tags: flutter, dart

[I am just following the tutorial, but why is the result different?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptGVk.png)

I don't know why it's not working, while my teacher can do it. I've searched through ChatGPT and others, but still couldn't find a solution. I just want my program to run.

Comment: I don't program in Dart either, but that looks like a warning. It's telling you that you shouldn't use print. Given that this language is mostly indicated for web development and mobile apps, you shouldn't expect to have a screen to `print` with Dart. You should use a logging feature to write data into that log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid \`print\` calls in production code. (Documentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531248/avoid-print-calls-in-production-code-documentation)

Comment: It's a warning, but it won't stop you from using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print`, it will print since it's just a warning.

The warning said you shouldn't use `print()` in production code. `print()` will print logs in release builds as well, which is something that shouldn't happen as some developers might log sensitive information.

You can get rid of the warning with below solution:

1. To remove the warning in that single line

```
// ignore: avoid_print
print('Hello World');
```

2. To remove the warning in that file

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
print('Hello World');
```

3. To remove the warning from the whole project.

Open analysis_options.yaml file and add this linter rule:

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    avoid_print: false
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good practice to use `print()` in production code.

Instead you can try using [logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) package, that is also a really comfortable log tool to use.